# Get all results of a One to many in 1 result

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to get all matching results from a one to many relationship in 1 result.

**Table structure**

```
Users              owr_rosterdata               
--------           --------                 
id| name           id | user | info
-----------        ---------------------
1 | nealvdv        1  | 1 | aaaa
2 | another        2  | 1 | bbbb
                   3  | 2 | cccc
                   4  | 2 | dddd
```

My current query is something like this (without the WHERE clauses)

```
        "
        SELECT owr_rosterdata.*, users.id, users.name FROM owr_rosterdata 
        INNER JOIN users ON owr_rosterdata.user = users.id
        "
```

**Current output**

**User 1**: 1, nealvdv, aaaa

**User 1**: 1, nealvdv, bbbb

**User 2**: 1, another, cccc

**User 2**: 1, another, dddd

> The whole point of this query is to avoid having multiple queries to
>   get all matching results of a user into 1 result.

**Desired output**

**User 1**: 1, nealvdv, aaaa, bbbb

**User 2**: 2, another, cccc, dddd

Thank you for any suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**`GROUP_CONCAT`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) for this:

```
SELECT users.id, users.name,
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT owr_rosterdata.info ORDER BY owr_rosterdata.info ASC ) 
FROM owr_rosterdata 
INNER JOIN users ON owr_rosterdata.user = users.id
GROUP BY users.id, users.name
```

Comment: I'm not sure who downvoted or why but I have read about the "GROUP_CONCAT". Is there no way to have it like it normally is rather then seperated by commas for example?